# How to display data every 10 minutes with daterange on mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display my data on the web every 10 minutes, I use daterange to display data based on two dates. this is data from my mysql:

```
2018-10-10 00:00:09
2018-10-10 00:01:09
2018-10-10 00:02:09
2018-10-10 00:03:09
~~
~~
data will increase every 1 minute
~~
2018-10-10 04:20:09
```

And this is the query that I use to display data based on two dates :

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE DATE(datetime) BETWEEN "'.$_POST["start_date"].'" AND  "'.$_POST["end_date"].'" ORDER BY 'id'
```

How to display data based on two dates at intervals of every 10 minutes ?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: And note that your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: I don't know what kind of application you are developing, but listen to @Strawberry. SQL Injection can be a very bad thing, It is one of the easiest ways of exploiting systems and is very easy to protect against it.